# How do I load a local html file using webview

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I am building an electron app where I am loading an html file using this code in development:

```
<webview id="foo" src="/src/documents/example.html" style="display:inline-flex; width:100%; height:550px"></webview>
```

This works well in development but once the app is packaged it shows a blank page.I have researched around and it seems using `__dirname` might fix the issue.

I am still very new to electron and can't figure out how to reach this path `(src="/src/documents/)` using `__dirname`.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I would share the solution I found around this.Basically ,you need to create a route for the page you want to load like this:

```
{
  path:'/example',
  name:'example',
  component: require('@/components/example').default
},
```

If you are using electron-vue,make sure the page extension is ".vue" and enclose the page content like this:

```
<template>
<html>
**Put the page content in here**
</html> 
</template>
```

In my case,I wanted to go to the page by clicking on a button,so i used Vue-router like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light"><a id="home"><router-link :to="{ name: 'example' }"> Button text </router-link></a>
</button>
```

Et voila!